# How can i fix this schema error in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

**1. the error**

> C:\Users\Jurjiu\Desktop\shit\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:502
>         throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
>         ^
>   MongooseError [MissingSchemaError]: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Employee".
>   Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
>       at new MissingSchemaError (C:\Users\Jurjiu\Desktop\shit\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\missingSchema.js:22:11)
>       at Mongoose.model (C:\Users\Jurjiu\Desktop\shit\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:502:13)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Jurjiu\Desktop\shit\controllers\employeeController.js:4:25)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Jurjiu\Desktop\shit\server.js:8:26)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
>       at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
>       at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
>   [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

**2. Code- from employeeController.js**

```js
    const express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    const mongoose=require('mongoose');
    const Employee=mongoose.model('Employee');


    router.get('/', ( req , res) => {
        res.render("employee/addOrEdit.hbs", {
            viewTitle : "Insert Employee"
        });
    });

    router.post('/', ( req , res) => {
        InsertRecord( req , res);
    });



    function InsertRecord(req,res){
        var employee = new Employee();
         employee.fullName = req.body.fullName;
         employee.mail = req.body.email;
         employee.mobile = req.body.mobile;
         employee.city = req.body.city;
         employee.save((err , doc) => {
        if(!err)
                 res.redirect('employee/list');
         else{
             console.log('Error during record insertion : ' + err);

         }
     });}


    router.get('/list', ( req , res) => {
        res.json('from list');
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

**Employee**

```js
    const mongoose=require('mongoose');

    var employeeSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
        fullname:{
            type : String
        },
        email:{
            type : String
        },
        mobile: {
            type : String
        },
        mobile: {
            type : String
        }


    });

    mongoose.model('Employee',employeeSchema);
    module.exports={Employee};`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign model, assig the model through

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('../models/[your_model]');

var User = mongoose.model('./models/['model']');
```

Comment: hey thanks! it say not that ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Employee' before initialization

Answer (score 0):

In the file of Employee Schema, ( assuming employee.js ), replace the last two lines with:

```js
module.exports = mongoose.model('Employee',employeeSchema);
```

And in the employeeController.js file, replace fourth line with:

```js
const Employee = require("./employee"),
```

Comment: hey thanks ! now it say cannot find module... `Error: Cannot find module './Employee'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Jurjiu\Desktop\shit\controllers\employeeController.js
- C:\Users\Jurjiu\Desktop\shit\server.js`

Comment: It's lowercase `e` in "`e`mployee" there. Basically name of the schema file without `.js`. Make sure the employee.js file is in same folder as employeeController.js